# Why was the monorail system discontinued?

Tags: trains, history, monorail

I'm a casual Lego enjoyer and decided to research some old sets and found out about the old monorail system.

My question is why was it discontinued? It was a pretty neat system and I could see something like it working well with modern themes (mostly Lego City), and why was it in so few sets?

Comment: [Is there a chance the track might bend?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGg5rfBfWT4)

Comment: I hear those things are awfully loud.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to https://forum.brickset.com/discussion/comment/57906/#Comment_57906 :

> The reason LEGO has stopped making monorail is threefold,
>
> One, the motors and track molds ran out and would be very expensive to replace.
>
> Two, no monorail set ever made any money, in fact despite trying several different types at high price points they all cost more to produce then they were sold for.
>
> Three, kids these days don't see them as exciting, they are from theme parks or airports, not a futuristic thing at all, in fact pretty boring.

On the subject of molds: according to https://bricknerd.com/home/lego-monorail-bring-it-back-or-build-your-own-7-6-21 ,

> The molds and the motor aren’t available anymore because they were produced by a contractor that no longer exists.

See also the question here: [What was wrong with monorails?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/what-was-wrong-with-monorails)

Comment: Changing times is certainly true in lots of cases. When I was a child, I saw vector polygon graphics as the wave of the future in video gaming. Nowadays, they are firmly retro and a sign of the 1980's.

Comment: Why didn't they set the price based on the production cost?

Comment: @SolomonUcko I would presume that sales would be minimal at a prices so high.